# Filter Array of cookies for a specific cookie and get value of a specific cookie in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

I am fixing some issue in a legacy module and came across this code which get the array of cookies from request object which can return null. The code looks for a specific cookie, if present then returns cookie value otherwise it returns null. Below is the existing code

```java
final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        final Cookie cookie = cookies[i];
        if ("random cookie".equals(cookie.getName())) {
            return cookie.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I refactored it to something like this

```java
final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if (cookies != null) {
    Optional<Cookie> cookie = Arrays.stream(cookies).
            filter(e -> "random cookie".equals(e.getName())).
            findAny();
    return cookie.isPresent() ? cookie.get().getValue() : null;
}
return null;
```

Can the above be refactored in a better way?

Comment: This is subjective, but I think the first code is more readable. If you cannot change the method signature and the original code works without problems, I would not change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be best to make the method return `Optional<String>` - but if you can't then how about this:

```java
final Cookie[] maybeCookies = request.getCookies();
return Optional.ofNullable(maybeCookies)
    .flatMap(cookies -> Arrays.stream(cookies)
         //Find the cookie if we can.
         .filter(e->"random cookie".equals(cookie.getName()))
         .findAny()
    )
    //If we have a matching cookie, return its value.
    .map(e->e.getValue())
    //otherwise return null to retain original behaviour
    .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would refactor this into a method which returns `Optional<String>`:

```
public Optional<String> getCookieValue(String name) {
   final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
   if(cookies == null) return Optional.empty();
   return Arrays.stream(cookies)
                .filter(e -> name.equals(e.getName()))
                .findAny().map(Cookie::getValue);
}
```

then the caller of this method would do any of these depending on how they intend to use the result:

```
getCookieValue("random cookie").ifPresent(e -> { ... });
getCookieValue("random cookie").orElse(null);
....
....
```

return `Optional<String>` to avoid dealing with *nullity* and let the user of this method decide what to do in the "no value case". This also reads better to the user of this API etc....

**However**, if you wish to persist with your current method signature then you can at least improve it to:

```
final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();
if(cookies == null) return null; // avoids if blocks
return Arrays.stream(cookies)
             .filter(e -> "random cookie".equals(e.getName()))
             .findAny()
             .map(Cookie::getValue)
             .orElse(null);
```

Comment: I think [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) is more appropriate since that is what the original loop did while [`findAny()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findAny--) "is free to select any element in the stream"

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Technically yes the imperative approach behaves like `findFirst` but does it really matter? 1) definitely not in this case as the stream **is not parallel** so both `findAny` and `findFirst` would behave the same 2) even if it was parallel all we want to know is **if any cookie has the value of `name`** and if so then get me the value. I wouldn't think there would be multiple cookies with the same name.... just because that's how the imperative approach behaved doesn't necessarily mean it _must exactly_ behave like so via a stream. but ultimately I am just going off OPs code.

Comment: if any cookie with the supplied name exists**

Comment: so the most important point to take from that is under the current implementation `findAny` and `findFirst` would both return the first element in a non parallel stream so using any of the aforementioned would suffice here (in-fact using `findAny` is probably the better option for this specific problem as we don't really care about the order especially when using parallel stream) and honestly I wouldn't expect that behaviour to change for sequential streams. but good shout though! ;)

Comment: This is sensible and exactly what I would have liked to do. However can't change the API method signature.

Comment: @RahulT Right. in which case the second solution is probably the best you can do via streams.

Comment: @MarcoLucidi the original loop had no possibility to express that it doesn’t care whether the match is first or any. That’s one of the advantages of the Stream API, now programmers can declare when it really doesn’t matter.

Comment: @OusmaneD. @Holger yeah, you both are right, probably it's better to use `findAny()`, thank you for the explanation. I'm sorry, I was too focused in "translating the loop to stream" and I failed to see the "big picture" of the problem. I apologize for my silly comment, regards.